# Log4net Root logger working, other one not

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have the following log4net configuration. For some reason the "root" logger works, which the "logger" logger does not.  I have tried switching the contents of the two and the other one will start working while whichever one is in "logger" does not.

The log4net Debugging does not appear to be outputting anything...? Checked console which is where I hear it's supposed to be output to.

Any advice?

Thank you!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, 
            log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
    <logger name="ConsoleLogger">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

The code I am using in the C# is:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log.config", Watch = true)]

private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Feeder));

Logger.Info("Message to Log");
```

Comment: So presumably you have code like `log = LogManager.GetLogger("ConsoleLogger")`?

Comment: Thanks stuartd, I added the code to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have created a named logger - `ConsoleLogger` - but then you are resolving a log object based on your `Feeder` type name.

Because there is no defined logger called `E.G.Namespace.Feeder`, log4net falls back to the root logger, which is what you have seen happening.

In order to use the `ConsoleLogger` you have to ask for it by name:

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("ConsoleLogger");
```

(Or alternatively rename it in the config file)

Comment: So that does indeed explain what is happening.  Do you know of a way to have like a second root, one that writes everything to the file, one that writes everything to the console BUT they have different logging levels?  I know how to do it with them both having the same logging level.

Thanks Stuart!!

Comment: Reason being because I have multiple feeders each loading with their own class. Would be nice to at some point be able to separately and easily log for individual classes, yet also log for all to both places with different levels.

Comment: You have I think two ways - 1) define everything in the config file or 2) set the levels dynamically at runtime.

Comment: For future reference for anyone coming across this question:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html#hierarchy

I ended up simply using the project, which was higher up in the hierarchy, which automatically wrote all my classes to the log.